# JFormattedTextField display commas and accept decimal points

Tags: java, swing, number-formatting

I am using to `JFormattedTextField` for inputting numbers with decimal points. The following is the formatter.

```
public static AbstractFormatterFactory createFormatter() {
    final NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    final InternationalFormatter formatter = new InternationalFormatter(format);
    formatter.setValueClass(Double.class);
    formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
    formatter.setOverwriteMode(true);
    formatter.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);
    return new DefaultFormatterFactory(formatter, formatter, formatter);
}
```

With `setAllowsInvalid(false)` periods are ignored, but commas are added every 3 digits as desired. With `setAllowsInvalid(true)` periods are accepted, but commas are not displayed until the focus changes.

Is there a way to have both behaviors?

Comment: Can create a custom extending from JFormattedTextField

Comment: I have, but what are you suggesting the extended class do/override?

Comment: Yes, you can override that method and create logic similar in order to support both..

Comment: What is the method you are referring to? The check on allow invalid is within the formatter and uses a private variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that JFormattedTextField is made to format differently when editing versus displaying and that was the root of my problem. I have found a very good, if not old, article on using JFormattedTextField that puts everything together nicely. http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/java-better-interfaces-via-jformattedtex/224700979